# How to do ((A.B).(C.D)) in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, cons

I'm trying to figure out how to do this using cons:

`((A . B) . (C . D))`

where `(A . B)` and `(C . D)` are in each cons cell

I've tried doing this `(cons (cons 'a 'b) (cons 'c 'd))` but it gives me this:

`((A.B) C . D)`

I also tried this: `(cons (cons 'a 'b) (cons (cons 'c 'd) ()))` but it gives me this:

`((A . B) (C . D))`

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: The second one looks like what you want. In what way is it not suitable?

Comment: @Anon: The second one doesn't have the middle dot. It's actually a different value, because there's a null (empty list) in there.

Answer (score 15):

The first one is what you want. They're equivalent. You can verify like this:

```
1 ]=> (cons (cons 'a 'b) (cons 'c 'd))

;Value 11: ((a . b) c . d)

1 ]=> (car (cons (cons 'a 'b) (cons 'c 'd)))

;Value 12: (a . b)

1 ]=> (cdr (cons (cons 'a 'b) (cons 'c 'd)))

;Value 13: (c . d)
```

Remember a list *is* a cons cell. The "car" is the head element of the list or the first half of the cons cell, and the cdr is the rest of the list, or the second element of the cons cell.

Another way to verify that they're equivalent:

```
1 ]=> '((a . b) . (c . d))

;Value 14: ((a . b) c . d)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Laurence! That's a cool trick if they're equivalent

Answer (score 7):

Just look at what you get back when you enter in a literal `((A . B) . (C . D))`:

```
* '((a . b) . (c . d))

((A . B) C . D)
```

There is a [defined algorithm](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_ace.htm) the Lisp printer uses to print out data structures built from pairs. Basically, you can't ever get a cons to be printed as a dotted pair inside parentheses when it is the CDR of another cons.

However, it is possible to re-configure the printer so that you get the behavior you are seeking, via [SET-PPRINT-DISPATCH](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set_pp.htm):

```
(set-pprint-dispatch 'cons
  (lambda (stream object)
    (format stream "(~W . ~W)" (car object) (cdr object))))
```

```
* '((a . b) . (c . d))

((A . B) . (C . D))
* (cons (cons 'a 'b) (cons 'c 'd))  ;The same object

((A . B) . (C . D))
```

Although in spite of that it would frankly be better in the long run if you got comfortable with reading the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean... I agree with the above comment that the last line of your code resembles the first, which you are matching against.

Here's a decent general resource for you anyhow: http://www-2.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for isn't possible because of how lists are represented in Lisp. When you create a list, you are creating a series of cons cells, where the car of the cell is the value of that element in the list, and the cdr is a reference to the next cons cell. Your desired cell, `((A . B) . (C . D))` means "create a cons cell where the car is `(A . B)` and the cdr is `(C . D)`". That is equivalent to a list where the first element is `(A . B)`, second element is `C` and the tail of the list is `D`, or `((A . B) C . D)`.

Comment: I downvoted, because you say it isn't possible, then explain why it is equivalent to his first attempt!

Comment: Fair. I was saying it was impossible to get the interpreter to give the output he wanted.